# SQL Server 2012 Pivot to Count Types of Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2012

I have a result set that looks like the below. Can anyone show me how to "pivot" this ,  so

```
datadate , timestart , timeend , datatype , datacount , datasum
2013-06-03 ,  20:00:00.0000000 ,  21:00:00.0000000 , 10 , 3 , 30
2013-06-03 ,  20:00:00.0000000 , 21:00:00.0000000 , 20 , 3 , 30
2013-06-03 ,  20:00:00.0000000 , 21:00:00.0000000 , 30 , 3 , 30
2013-06-03 ,  19:00:00.0000000 , 20:00:00.0000000 , 10 , 2 , 20
```

can turn into this

```
date  ,  timestart   timeend   , type10count , type10sum , type20count , type20sum , type30count , type30sum
2013-06-03 , 20:00:00.0000000 , 21:00:00.0000000 , 3 , 30 , 3 , 30 , 3 , 30
2013-06-03 , 19:00:00.0000000 , 20:00:00.0000000 , 2 , 20 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
```

I was trying to make a PIVOT to avoid a CASE statement and redefining a new table but am coming up short.
How should this be done?

```
    declare @starttable table
    (
    datadate date , timestart time , timeend time , datatype tinyint , datacount int , datasum int
    )
    insert into @starttable  
    select '2013-06-03' , '20:00:00' , '21:00:00' , 10 , 3 , 30
    union all
    select '2013-06-03' , '20:00:00' , '21:00:00' , 20 , 3 , 30
    union all
    select '2013-06-03' , '20:00:00' , '21:00:00' , 30 , 3 , 30
    union all
    select '2013-06-03' , '19:00:00' , '20:00:00' , 10 , 2 , 20

    select datadate , timestart , timeend 
    from ( select datadate , timestart , timeend , datacount ,datasum from @starttable ) as t1
    pivot ( sum(datasum) for datatype in (datacount,datasum) ) as t2
-- yes i know sql server gongs this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is pivot syntax that works:

```
select datadate, timestart, timeend, [10], [20], [30]
from ( select datadate , timestart, timeend, datatype, datacount, datasum
       from @starttable
     ) t1
pivot (sum(datasum) for [datatype] in ([10], [20], [30])
      ) t2;
```

The first thing you need is `datatype` in the inner subquery.  The second thing is the list of values in the pivot statement.

To get both the count and the sum in the same query, you need to "align" the data:

```
select datadate, timestart, timeend, [10sum], [10count], [20count], [20sum], [30count], [30sum]
from (select datadate, timestart, timeend, cast(datatype as varchar(255))+'count' as datatype, datacount as thedata
      from starttable
      union all
      select datadate, timestart, timeend, cast(datatype as varchar(255))+'sum' as datatype, datasum as thedata
      from starttable
     ) t
pivot (sum(thedata) for [datatype] in ([10sum], [10count], [20count], [20sum], [30count], [30sum])
      ) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the result that you want you will have to look at unpivoting the `datacount` and `datasum` columns first, then apply the pivot function.

The unpivot of the data will take the multiple columns and return multiple rows which will allow for the data rotation with the `datatype` values much easier. Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can easily unpivot the data using the UNPIVOT function or you can use CROSS APPLY with a VALUES clause.

```
select t.datadate, t.timestart, t.timeend, 
  'type'+cast(t.datatype as varchar(2))+ replace(c.col, 'data', '') as col, c.value
from starttable t
cross apply
(
  values ('datacount', datacount), ('datasum', datasum)
) c (col, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6345a/6). This will give a result that include multiple columns and it also has a new computed column that contains the values that will be pivoted on:

```
|   DATADATE |        TIMESTART |          TIMEEND |         COL | VALUE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-06-03 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 21:00:00.0000000 | type10count |     3 |
| 2013-06-03 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 21:00:00.0000000 |   type10sum |    30 |
| 2013-06-03 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 21:00:00.0000000 | type20count |     3 |
| 2013-06-03 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 21:00:00.0000000 |   type20sum |    30 |
```

Then you apply a PIVOT to this result:

```
select datadate, timestart, timeend, 
  type10count, type10sum, type20count, type20sum, type30count, type30sum
from
(
  select t.datadate, t.timestart, t.timeend, 
    'type'+cast(t.datatype as varchar(2))+ replace(c.col, 'data', '') as col, c.value
  from starttable t
  cross apply
  (
    values ('datacount', datacount), ('datasum', datasum)
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for col in (type10count, type10sum, type20count, type20sum, type30count, type30sum)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6345a/8)

Now if you have an unknown number of `datatype` values, then you could use dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('type'+cast(t.datatype as varchar(2))+c.col) 
                    from starttable t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      values ('count', 1), ('sum', 2)
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by t.datatype, c.col, c.so
                    order by t.datatype, c.so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT ',isNull(' + QUOTENAME('type'+cast(t.datatype as varchar(2))+c.col) 
                                      +', 0) as '+QUOTENAME('type'+cast(t.datatype as varchar(2))+c.col) 
                    from starttable t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      values ('count', 1), ('sum', 2)
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by t.datatype, c.col, c.so
                    order by t.datatype, c.so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT datadate, timestart, timeend,' + @colsNull + ' 
             from
            (
              select t.datadate, t.timestart, t.timeend, 
                ''type''+cast(t.datatype as varchar(2))+ replace(c.col, ''data'', '''') as col, c.value
              from starttable t
              cross apply
              (
                values (''datacount'', datacount), (''datasum'', datasum)
              ) c (col, value)
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6345a/14). Both versions give a result:

```
|   DATADATE |        TIMESTART |          TIMEEND | TYPE10COUNT | TYPE10SUM | TYPE20COUNT | TYPE20SUM | TYPE30COUNT | TYPE30SUM |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-06-03 | 19:00:00.0000000 | 20:00:00.0000000 |           2 |        20 |           0 |         0 |           0 |         0 |
| 2013-06-03 | 20:00:00.0000000 | 21:00:00.0000000 |           3 |        30 |           3 |        30 |           3 |        30 |
```

Comment: I need a way to give this answer as well as the previous one the accepted-answer checkmark. I learned a ton in the last 12 hours from both replies. Thanks!